# Is there any usage of BJT amplifiers besides audio amplification?

Tags: amplifier, bjt

Discrete transistor based circuits can not run at very high frequency due to the capacative loading and possibly other issues like propagation delays.

Talking specifically about discrete transistor circuit based BJT amplifiers, is there any use of them besides making audio amplifiers?

The keyword here is "discrete" transistor circuit that is "analog circuit" and not IC design or digital design.

Comment: Your initial assertion appears to be incorrect.

Comment: I am asking here, because I do not know.

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/transistor-switch-bjt/

Comment: @All - *Please be nice* and comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending (or worse). Some comments here were deleted after being flagged. Although [polite constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756) is allowed in comments (with the emphasis on *polite* & *constructive*) anything snarky / mocking / condescending etc. is NOT allowed and will be removed, as happened here. Thanks for your cooperation. (Remember, people ask questions because they don't know something. Don't mock them for that!)

Comment: I build a lot of discrete analog stuff, usually using BJTs, because they are cheaper than MOSFETs. Regulators, simple opamps, or even bad bandgap refs and such. Building them with transistors keeps the BOM small and it can be adjusted for various special requirements easily which is not always possible with jelly-bean op-amps.

Comment: Basically almost all products in the 60's and early 70's used BJT's for every semiconductor function you can imagine in TV's and oscilloscopes. These have migrated with the advent of high impedance gain FETs and CMOS.

Comment: Consider discrete MOSFET amplifiers are rarer than discrete BJT amps. I think you're focusing on the wrong thing. Is your question actually "Are discrete BJTs obsolete outside of audio?" Because your question, as is, seems arbitrarily posed treating something as if it were a unique or extreme case when it is neither, and eliminating potential answers for no discernible reason. Both audio and amplifiers are not the only analog circuits. There are thousands of non-audio, non-amp analog applications. You have rejected all of these plus power circuits and circuits requiring just one critical BJT.

Comment: Your first sentence is a statement, not a question.

Comment: See the question is being posed because I know that discrete BJT (not IC design) can be used to build audio amplifier. Audio signals have low frequency. The question is, should be, what is the use of BJTs in world today besides making audio amplifiers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BJTs are used in a lot of applications, from DC to microwaves.

Some low frequency applications besides audio are DC amplifiers, voltage regulators, function generators, and video circuits. Linear power supplies use BJTs as pass elements, as well as for error and reference amplifiers.

At higher frequencies they are used as RF amplifiers, both in receivers and transmitters. They are used as RF power amplifiers up to kilowatts of power. BJTs exist that function into the hundreds of Gigahertz frequency range.

Think of almost any electronic device made around 50 years ago (between the time vacuum tubes were dominant and the time ICs became prevalent) and it probably used bipolar transistors.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a scientific instrument designer: I don't do audio. I use plenty of BJTs in many roles. Advantages of BJTs relative to FETs include:

- Low input-referred voltage noise.
- Low input capacitance.
- Low input thresholds.
- Very high, predictable transconductance.
- High available gain-bandwith product.
- High radiation tolerance.
- Wide variety of available discrete parts.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I believe I had read some papers long ago suggesting that MOSFETs were typically more radiation resistant than BJTs.  But maybe that depends on the specifics of the actual parts one selects.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the historic use of BJTs in TTL logic, there is an inherent problem with hFE Max/min ratios in production. Some companies such as ROHM specialize in binned BJTs with low hFE ratios and essentially lead the industry in digital transistor switches.

Naturally, BJTs have been used for many applications such as RF,  high-speed analog switches using common base mode with many for multiplexing channels or level shifters and high voltage switches with FET inputs called IGBTs.

Early Scopes and TVs used BJTs for everything from power supplies, voltage regulators, video clamps, video DACs, high-speed SRAM, and hundreds more applications.

You can review ROHM's digital transistor options here.
https://www.rohm.com/products/transistors#bipolar-transistors

[image]

Solutions include:
https://www.ecstuff4u.com/2018/05/application-of-bjt.html

### Method of finding solutions

Socratic search method of using coarse then finer search and answers in a web search.

e.g. web search

1. = [BJT applications analog](https://www.google.com/search?q=BJT%20applications%20analog&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsY9lFl57ICRxg_LA_rG_R5pBds7Pw%3A1670505251449&ei=I-ORY8yBG8OYkPIP5POV0Ak&ved=0ahUKEwiMn-6Ajer7AhVDDEQIHeR5BZoQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=BJT%20applications%20analog)
2. = BJT applications analog RF
3. = BJT applications Automotive

### Engineering Philosphy

W. K. C. Guthrie in The Greek Philosophers sees it as an error to regard the Socratic method as a means by which one seeks the answer to a problem, or knowledge. Guthrie claims that the Socratic method actually aims to demonstrate one's ignorance. Socrates, unlike the Sophists, did believe that knowledge was possible, but believed that the first step to knowledge was recognition of one's ignorance. Guthrie writes, "[Socrates] was accustomed to say that he did not himself know anything, and that the only way in which he was wiser than other men was that he was conscious of his own ignorance, while they were not. The essence of the Socratic method is to convince the interlocutor that whereas he thought he knew something, in fact, he does not."[[8]](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Socratic_method)

I conclude that this Socratic (web search) Method should be better called the ***[Guthrie Method](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Edwin_Ray_Guthrie)***. **Assume you know nothing about the answer.**  Whereas this site uses experts who know something about the answer but the question needs better scope details prompted by comments. (Socratic Method).

There is an [online electronic simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMjJzgDgCwCYt2wOyLoEBsBIcECVlApgLTIBQALiNnKUotkgJx9kfCE3AgGYSORgBmNJi5h%20cTLIqJYIACZ0AZgEMArgBtWbDlx59Z2CMPFjJkXndKyVYbJgIF0s2XQJKRkweVUuTlJEWUQkLV1DU3MAd0tuByikUggwZjTEQSRcASEc8HzS7IgsxHK8gCcq-gyi23FNRpBbCBbuu36OmErCmzGIdryAJSr23iDJ8UxqcVzUZibR6qrsb3EqLp7ihYHdzA6qEaK6%20xKbioBnY%2035jj3ckEMTB7oN57Odu8OMM0kdXoFzq88k8Ic9YQD7J8DN9fk0jgD4UDNFc%20ACtrggohKui9uj0ITmABzHbk2Zgc65Kn9Gq0o6yemrZgADyQcH41iQ6HsiAQkO4AEUiTyAkIYt04LIeNwxSBxdhmEA) written by a programmer named FALSTAD. You will find lots of basic designs built in to simulate.
[image]  It can do FFT and users can choose hFE , but it is constant not nonlinear when saturated to 10% of hFE.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of potential use of BJT for digital circuits. However, what about analogue domain where we are doing design using discrete transistors and not IC design?

Comment: The unpredictability of Hfe is not a serious problem if you design around transconductance and treat base current as (poorly controlled) leakage. Read Horowitz and Hill.

Comment: @JohnDoty  I know H&H very well.   The infamous Hammer drivers  IC's with Darlingtons https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2803a.pdf  were these designed with gm, if so what are the specs?  It seems they only give hFE

Comment: @JohnDoty  BTW I agree with you one gm but also include Rce, but then read Bob Pease as he vehemently agrees on gm and then tells a writer his fantastic Op Amp also has very high well-matched hFE.  (instead of well-matched very high gm ??)  https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21799049/whats-all-this-transconductance-stuff-anyhow   BTW I started life as an aerospace instrumentation R&D engineer in 1975.

Comment: The transconductance for the Darlington combination is gm_d=(gm_1+gm_2)/2=Ic_d/2Vt.

Comment: Which Vt?  Vin with resistor or without?

Comment: @LvW  gm is never constant nor given in datasheets, how does that help if it not ideal?

Comment: @Tony Stewart I must admit that I do not fully understand you remarks. Did I claim that gm would be constant? Of course, it is not in the data sheet - because it is a direct function of Ic. But you know all of this ......therefore, I am a bit confused.....

Comment: @LvW It is not possible to use gm in designing with a  Darlington with embedded resistors since unless an input is defined,  Id cannot be calculated from Vin and Vcc/Rd,   thus gm=Id/Vt is just academic and has no use.  There are many other non linear problems equally unable to use gm to design a solution , so **that's my point.**  and also why it is not plotted in datasheets

Comment: @Tony Stewart ...embedded resistors? My comment was related to a "naked" Darlington only. For a single BJT we are using the transconductance for calculating the voltage gain (have you a better method?) and the same applies for Darlington, does it not? Of course, gm is - more or less - an idealized quantity. Which method do you use for finding the voltage gain?

Comment: re: * The infamous Hammer drivers IC's with Darlingtons st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2803a.pdf were these designed with gm, if so what were the specs?*    It seems they only give hFE in the datasheet as hFE=1000 min for those reasons.     I rely on hFE for the variation of current gain with Ib. Vcb conductance and Rce rise in Vce during fringe saturation up to 2V at max current using all the plots pf current gain and tolerances in tables for hFE. This is why Ic/Ib is fixed for different ranges of hFE < 200 ,> 200 and > 500 to ratios of 10, 20 and 50 and has nothing gained by converting gm

Comment: When base resistance and collector Rce resistance become significant deviations to the expected ideal model results, gm is of little use.  Saturation current Is, deviations and ideality factors prevail to define some differences in transistors.

Comment: I know that we can build a lot of stuff using BJTs. The thing is that when we use discrete transistors, they are not matched. The signal path between the transistors also add propagation delay and capacitance.

Comment: Matching requirements are solved by using Ic < 1mA or using an IC with a matched pair. The layout can be matched too. Consider all the functions in a 6 transistor Radio

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth I can say that I've built AM radio amplifiers with the common & ordinary 2N3904 BJTs.

Even a transistor with a fT of only 300 Mhz like the 2N3904 can easily handle up to 10 Mhz (and more with good design), let alone AM radio up to 1.7 Mhz. The discrete design of Common Emitter between Emitter Followers worked great, whereas if I had used ordinary Op Amps - it wouldn't have worked, because an Op Amp with a 3-4 MHz bandwidth probably can't amplify more than 0.5 Mhz and even that's a lot for such Op Amp. I might have needed a more expensive Op Amp that's also not available for breadboards (in DIP form).

The main point also is that inside chips it's the same BJT transistors in the same configs as used or could be used discreetly. Broadly speaking, there isn't one design in chips and another discreetly. It just a matter of form factor.

In particular, while discrete designs are not associated with a feedback loop as often, all the same feedback is not a chip property and could be added discretely just as easily - I've had a chance to build a 15 transistor BJT OP Amp discreetly and used it in negative feedback configs - by wiring the output back to the inverting terminal.

On Mouser and Digikey there many BJTs with transition frequencies of dozens of GHz (& accordingly they have a much lower capacitance than ordinary).

The transistors inside chips also don't have very different capacitances than discrete ones, & as a result are limited in frequency in a similar way to discrete ones. Although the more compact form factor of ICs helps with transmission line issues.

Comment: When we use discrete transistor, we might not get them to match very well. The large signal paths add another limitation on what the circuit can do.

Comment: I agree about the longer paths for Ghz frequencies (more transmission line stuff). The matching you mean in hFe (beta) values? You know, it strikes me that most designs are independent of that to begin with, and I'm not sure that the transistor form factor makes much difference here (the later admittedly I don't know for sure, but about the former, namely beta independent designs - that's the common thing I believe). Anyhow I'm less sure about the advanced stuff, but for projects in the low MHz range, you might need an Op Amp with a 100 mhz bandwith to do the same job as an ordinary CE amp.

Comment: (What limits the gain of an Op Amp is not the transistor but the need to add capacitor which is a short circuit at high frequencies. Otherwise the feedback loop might have conditions favourable to high frequency oscillations).